# How to make authentication to this API (StarkBank) via Postman?

Tags: authentication, postman, private-key

I am attempting to utilize the API available at https://starkbank.com/docs/api#introduction.

The provided instructions outline the process of creating a (sk, pk) pair for an ECDSA curve. Additionally, it is mentioned that ECDSA is used to authenticate requests, which implies that a secp256k1 private key must be generated to sign requests made to the API. Furthermore, it is necessary to register the corresponding public key to enable the validation of these requests.

I have successfully used the SDK for Python, and I am familiar with the process of setting the sk in the SDK. However, I am currently facing challenges in consuming the API via Postman, as I am unsure of how to configure the sk in Postman.

Could anyone provide assistance with this issue?